# Expo, how to save file from app directory to local directory

Tags: react-native, expo

Im new to React Native and im using Expo to create an iOS and Android app. All I want to do is save a file that is stored in the application to the users device.
Using `downloadAsync` and `shareAsync` I can download from a remote url and save it but I can not download or just share a local file stored in in the apps directory.
Ive tried

`await shareAsync('file://./manuals/mypdf.pdf');`

`await shareAsync('./manuals/mypdf.pdf');`

`await shareAsync(require('./manuals/mypdf.pdf'));`

and I get the error

`[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: You don't have access to provided file.]` or the app just crashes

Comment: With the app directory, are you referring to assets?

Comment: @user18309290 yes

Answer (score 0):

Use [loadAsync](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v47.0.0/sdk/asset/#loadasyncmoduleid) to download asset data to a local file in the device's cache directory. After that the asset file is accessible like any other file.

```
const [{ localUri }] = await Asset.loadAsync(require('./manuals/mypdf.pdf'));
```